# customizing navbar with image as a title

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode5

I want to add a image in the navbar as title. I'm using the following code in AppDelegate.m file

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"akskeving_logo.png"]];
```

I'm gettin the following error: Property 'navigationItem'not found on object of type 'HsAppDelegate'

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the `navigationItem` property of your app delegate, but it doesn’t have that property. `navigationItem` is a property of `UIViewController`. Something along these lines (details may be different for your app):

<s>`self.rootViewController.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"akskeving_logo.png"]];`</s>

**Edit:** actually, that is probably not exactly what you want to do. You should be accessing the `navigationItem` of the view controller that you are *presenting* in the navigation controller. So,

```
self.somePresentedViewController.navigationItem.titleView = …;
```